# IF you had a territorial struggle based on magic, how would it play out?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, geography

A large part of the political power in my world building for my book is based around a concept called "grinding" where a faction would gradually amass influence and natural resources by infusing the place with magical influence related to a chosen Patron Diety using seals, runes and chants.

Let's say you have a place that's sacred to the Naga's(serpent people), like a lake or stream in the desert. A solar deity of some sort might seek to wrest control of an area from the Nagas to gain access to said spring that has treasure in it, or special magical properties. Alternately, from just a geographical standpoint, oasises are rare and valuable in a desert and could be used to help feed his adherents that he's pacted with.

Said deity would send a magi in to nullify the area of any Naga influences and possibly wage warfare with the Nagas themselves. After winning, he would engrave seals in the dirt around the oasis or do a ritual to "seal" the place of external influences.

My question is, what implications could this possibly have for the wider colonial and political sphere in the book beside the land grab concept? What are some ways it can manifest in the book itself? What are some other political maneuvers that I can use that involve magic?

Just need some ideas here.

Comment: I doubt it would change much unless the magic inside the sphere of influence is influential. We don’t know if the deity can just incinerate anyone it likes within the area. We don’t know how difficult it is to nullify the influence and how vulnerable they are when they do. We don’t know how much the magic is part of warfare, do they throw an explosive fireball on a whim mid-combat or are they closer to artillery pieces that need to prepare each shot, functioning as moving canons? We need to know more to answer this.

Comment: Hope long does this "grinding" take? If a hostile faction comes in, can they seize the power quickly, or do they need to "grind" away the old power before adding their own?

Comment: Hello @AnnaGibson, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. We're lenient with new users, but please be aware that this is an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) that violates a number of [help] rules including being open-ended, hypothetical, too broad, and story-based. Further, asking more than one question per post is an actual reason to close the question. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum and expects specific questions to solve specific problems. Finally per the [help/on-topic], we help build worlds, not tell stories.

Comment: Sorry about this. I’ll do better next time.

Comment: @Demigan the sphere of influence is influential but it largely depends on the type of diety that's weilding the power. A solar diety can come in and dry up the oasis, causing a neighboring settlements only source of water to die out. Magic and technology are built into warfare, and various grid configuration need to be prepared ahead of time for the Portal to open that suffuses an area with energy. It may take days for the dieties magic to seep through enough to cause changes.

Comment: @Kyyshak It takes some time, usually hours to actually seize power after the hostile faction moves in. They can't just pop up and take over within a few minutes. The on top of needs to be placed under a mandala and the dieties energy gradually seeps through. The process can be disrupted anytime during the intermediate period between complete lack of control and full control.

Comment: Please are the information from your comment into your question. These details are important to everyone looking into your question, not only the users asking after it specifically :)

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

1: Each Deity's favour/patronage could come with certain gifts/boons/perks. Let's take the Naga people/Deity - it could be that this renders the inhabitants of that area immune to Snake Bites (or the Snakes don't attack).

In an area that has a high population of Snakes, this could make taking over of the area *extremely* unpopular with the locals.

Other Deity's could have competing ones - such as the Sun Deity might make crops grow well, whereas the Moon Deity (presuming here) may help the inhabitants see in the blackest darkness - you have a tension there between good for Farming and good for Hunting - which, depending on the inhabitants and what they view as more beneficial.

2: Alliances! The Bane of European politics.

So, let's say that the Naga Deity are under threat by the Mongoose Deity (Damn RikiTiki), they agree to an alliance with the Sun Deity - The Sun deity agrees to heat the area where the Naga's fight, boosting their performance, in exchange for the Snakes defending the underground tunnels against incursion from the Moon Deity.

As with all Political Alliances, Back-stabbing, Double Crossing, Competing interests and all that good story material are assumed.

3: Counter-Magi.

Individuals that whilst not having any innate skill with Magic per-se, they are extremely sensitive to Magic Users - They are rare and are as highly prized (if not moreso) than Magi, as they allow an area to guard against Magi incursion.

4: The Magical Bureau of Seals and Glyph Maintenance.

A massive bureaucracy whose sole function is the routine inspection and maintenance of various Seals and Glyphs. Both from natural wear and tear, accidental destruction (such as a natural disaster) and reporting any suspicious signs of Grinding.

Could be used entirely straight faced, or could be written as a slightly comedic parody of present day institutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Speed**

In real life you can go into a place, kill everyone there, and then build bases and station soldiers. This makes the place stronger and easier to defend than it was at the start. Your system works in principle the same way. But it is free of the practical limitations of castles and soldiers. It takes ages to build a castle. You might not have enough stone blocks, or enough space troops to station there.

For the purposes of story, this is very good. It allows a small group of heroes to sneak around the land, disenchanting the five magical seals on the desert. These can be undone by a single talented mage. But they are hidden. It is a mystery and a race against time.

You may also declare that once the seals are removed, they effect disappears instantly. The enemy glyphs makes their soldiers need no sleep. We sneak in and destroy the glyph. Meanwhile our army launches an attack when they see the enemy soldiers all collapse from exhaustion.